# Is $|\langle Ax,x\rangle| \leq \langle |A|x,x\rangle$ in a complex Hilbert space?

Tags: inequality, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, trace

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space, $A$ a bounded operator and $|A|$ the unique positive square root of $A^*A$. In a comment in [Bounded self adjoint operator can be written as difference of positive operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2150811) it is suggested that $|\langle Ax,x\rangle| \leq \langle |A|x,x\rangle$, and that this is a consequence of the [Polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity). How?

I'm trying to show that $A$ has an absolutely convergent trace $\sum\langle Ae_i,e_i\rangle$ if $|A|$ has.

Related: [Does $|\langle x,Ax\rangle |=\langle x,|A|x\rangle$ for bounded operators on Hilbert space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251477)

Comment: How do you define a trace class operator?

Comment: @Aweygan See edit. I meant "has a trace", not is trace class. See also this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749799

Comment: This is true only if A is a selfadjoint bounded linear operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|\langle Ax, x\rangle|\leq \langle |A|x,x\rangle$ is **NOT** true for  a general bounded operator $A$.

**Example.** $A=\left(\begin{array} & 0  & 1\\
 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$,$x=\left(\begin{array} & 2\\ 1
\end{array}\right)$

---

We call $A$ is trace class if $|A|$ is, which is precisely the definition.

Comment: If I am not missing something, doesn't your example give $2 \leq 4$?

Comment: @lan sorry，I have corrected my answer, and there is also an example in the answer of  the related problem you give.

Comment: +1 I'm aware of the definition, which made me ask this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749799